# Hacked with spam in GSC isn't spam at all. It's text. How do I solve that?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search

I have an issue with Google Search Console's Security Issues.
I'm showing this warning:

> **Hacked with spam**
>
> A hacker may have modified your site to contain spammy content. To protect visitors to your site, Google’s search results may label your site’s pages as hacked. We may also show an older, clean version of your site.
>
> Content injection
> These pages appear to be modified by a hacker with the intent of spamming search results.

Suspicious snippet given is simply a line of text in `<p></p>` tags. That's it.

And that text is not injected by hackers. It's our text that we've placed on pages ourselves.
This issue makes our search results appear with "this site may be hacked" on SERPs and it hurts our CTR.

Any idea on why this could be happening and how could this be saved? We don't want to remove the text from pages as it's required. I've requested a review 2 weeks ago but it still shows as *Request in process*.

How do we prove Google that it's not a hack?

**UPD: I'm attaching a screenshot**
[image]

Comment: There's got to be a way to remove the `<p></p>` tag from your site. I'm sure you can put some other sort of placeholder in its spot.

Comment: @Michaeld why should I remove/replace <p> tag for a text paragraph? This sounds ridiculous.

Comment: Might be useful to add the actual offending snippet to your question. Also, have you used Fetch As Google to check you're seeing the same thing Googlebot is?

Comment: Googlebot is largely an algorithm now. It's a lot of machine learning. If it doesn't like the text you have between the `<p>` tag you can choose to remove it, or the bot might continue to flag you. Everything in life isn't always fair, and not everything makes sense sometimes. If the bot doesn't like the text between the tags the simplest thing you might be able to do is simply change it to something else. The Google algorithm is clearly amazing, though it's not 100% unglitched either. Just my suggestion. I don't know why the bot flagged you for this, and you haven't shown the text.

Comment: Off the top of my head, I'm going to guess that maybe Google found hacked sites with that same line of text on your site. So that line of text is associated with other hacked sites. And by leaving it on your site maybe it thinks your site got hacked as well.

Comment: @GDav is perfectly correct. Otherwise we can only guess and guess poorly. Please add the offending text. Without it, there simply is not enough detail. Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc I have added a screenshot with snippet

Comment: @GDav I have added a screenshot with snippet

Comment: Looks innocuous enough. I assume you've consulted Google's documentation on this? I'd suggest following that.

Comment: Maybe you could take a screenshot of the text and put that screenshot onto your site instead of the actual text?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller we have temporarily removed this text from the pages, waiting to see the result

Comment: Would it surprise you that porn and hacker/spam activity may have a correlation? While this snippet isn't enough for me to mark a page or site as hacked, I can easily see how this snippet was isolated as a clue.

Comment: You could simply replace the snippet with a link to an 'about models' or 'legal information' or similar page. Be careful with the link text of course! I would keep the link text as innocuous as possible. Cheers!!

Comment: It's not really possible for users to be able to answer this definitively, other than to suggest removing or replacing the text with an image and use trial & error. If you figure out something that might be helpful to others in the future and want to add that as an answer, add a comment here.